# iOS Simulator Is Not Working

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, ios-simulator

I am writing my first swift app from Beginning iPhone Development with Swift.

OS X - 10.10.5
Xcode - 7.0 (7A220)

When I run my app, I notice two things:

First, the simulator is a completely black screen. I am pretty sure the expected result should be black characters on a white background.

And second, when I exit the hello world app, Xcode displays the "Invalid Device State" message.

I Googled the issue to death and was unable to find anything that helped in any way whatsoever.

Unfortunately, I am stuck at the very beginning of my attempt to learn Swift. With this in mind, I would gratefully appreciate any useful input.

Thank you VERY much, David

Comment: With the simulator open try command+R.  After it resets do command+Q.  Then try running your app again.

Comment: What is the output of 'xcrun simctl list'?  Can you boot the simulator from Simulator.app successfully?